# SQL query select on one criteria if second criteria is false

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to come up with a SQL query to an Access database.  Here is a sample table which will help explain the problem I'm having:

```
ID     Status
-------------
123    Pass
123    Fail
456    Pass
789    Pass
789    Fail
012    Fail
```

I want to pull all `ID`'s which have a `Status=Pass` but do NOT have `Status=Fail`.

So from the table above, the only record that would get pulled would be:

```
456   Pass
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, *please* highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `<br>` tags, either!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Status
FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE Status = 'Fail')
  AND Status = 'Pass'
```

Small comment: `AND Status = 'Pass'` is not required in this case because there are only two Statuses and if the first condition is true the second one will also be true ([tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29)) but I decided to leave it for better indication.

[It works.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43f8e/4)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` predicate:

```
SELECT  *
FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE t1.Status ='Pass'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM Tablename AS t2
               WHERE t1.Id = t2.ID AND t2.status = 'Fail')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELCT * FROM table WHERE status = 'Pass' AND
id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE status ='Fail')
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information, along with your answer?